# difference between global authentication and local authentication in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, autowired

Hello GUYS I am new in spring security, I found article about authentication global (@Autowired configure) and local authentication (@Override configure)

could you tell me what is the difference between @Autowired configure() and @Override configure.

//Global

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth
.inMemoryAuthentication()
.withUser("admin").password("admin@password").roles("ROLE_ADMIN");
}
}
```

//local

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth
.inMemoryAuthentication()
.withUser("admin").password("admin@password").roles("ROLE_ADMIN");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at it is that the global `AuthenticationManager` is "global" because it can be **shared** across the application as a bean, so when you `@Autowire` an `AuthenticationManager`, you must be configuring the global `AuthenticationManager`. If not, the `AuthenticationManager` you configure locally as you do above will only exist within the context of your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Take a look at [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture#_authentication_and_access_control) in the Spring website.

Answer (score 0):

The Authentication and Access Control guide ( the same NatFar has provided link to) describes the following

> Sometimes an application has logical groups of protected resources
>   (e.g. all web resources that match a path pattern /api/**), and each
>   group can have its own dedicated AuthenticationManager. Often, each of
>   those is a ProviderManager, and they share a parent. The parent is
>   then a kind of "global" resource, acting as a fallback for all
>   providers.

The [image](https://github.com/spring-guides/top-spring-security-architecture/raw/master/images/authentication.png) depicts the global (parent) and local resources , which is self explanatory

Also go through the links :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4571

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4324